# Getting "Cannot charge a customer that has no active card" on php stripe

Tags: php, stripe-payments

I'm trying to create a customer before i charge them. on my `charge.php` file i have this.

```
if (isset($_POST['stripeToken'])) {   
 
    \Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey('___stripe_secret_key_____');

    $api_error = false;
    $token = $_POST['stripeToken'];
    try { 
     
                         $customer = \Stripe\Customer::create(array(
                             "name" => $name,
                             "email" => $email,
                             "source" => $token,
                             "metadata" => ['id' => $uid]
                         ));
     
                         $stripe_id = $customer->id;
     
                         //update stripe ID to DB
                         User::model()->updateByPk($uid, array('stripe_id' => $stripe_id));
     
                         
                     } catch(Exception $e) {  
                         $api_error = $e->getMessage();
                     } 
     if(empty($api_error) && $stripe_id) {
     
                     try { 
                         $charge = \Stripe\Charge::create(
                             array(
                                 'customer' => $stripe_id, //customer id
                                 'amount' => $_POST['stripe-amount'],
                                 'currency' => strtolower($_POST['stripe-currency']),
                                 'description' => 'US Report',
                                 'metadata' => [
                                                 'Currency' => $_POST['stripe-currency'],
                                                 'Invoice' => $_POST['ref_id'],
                                             ],
                                'receipt_email' => $email,
                             ), array (
                                 'idempotency_key' => preg_replace('/[^a-z\d]/im', '', $_POST['idempotency']),
                             )
                         );
                     } catch(\Stripe\Exception\CardException $e) {
                        // Since it's a decline, \Stripe\Exception\CardException will be caught
                        $api_error = 'Status is:' . $e->getHttpStatus() . '<br />';
                        $api_error .=  'Type is:' . $e->getError()->type . '<br />';
                        $api_error .=  'Code is:' . $e->getError()->code . '<br />';
                        // param is '' in this case
                        $api_error .=  'Param is:' . $e->getError()->param . '<br />';
                        $api_error .=  'Message is:' . $e->getError()->message . '<br />';
                      }
```

I'm using my own HTML form for the credit card , expiry and ccv. and included `https://js.stripe.com/v3/` in my page.

When i submit my payment i get this error

```
Charge creation failed! Status is:402
Type is:card_error
Code is:missing
Param is:card
Message is:Cannot charge a customer that has no active card
```

Any idea what i'm missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Didn't need this before, but I added it and now my code works again.

No idea why :p

```
\Stripe\Customer::createSource(
    $stripe_id,
    array('source' => $token)
);
```

Added this before my `$charge = \Stripe\Charge::create()`

Answer (score 0):

The only path that I see here that would cause that error is if $_POST['stripeToken'] is blank or null. I don't see that you're checking for that. If you look in your Stripe Dashboard logs, you should be able to see the exact parameters sent by your script to the "create customer" endpoint.

Beyond that, if you're still stuck I'd send the request ID (req_xxx) to Stripe Support along with your example code so that someone can take a closer look.

Answer (score 0):

Try to pass Stripe token in `source` parameter when creating the charge as well.

```php
$charge = \Stripe\Charge::create(
                         array(
                             'customer' => $stripe_id, //customer id
                             'source' => $token,
                             'amount' => $_POST['stripe-amount'],
                             'currency' => strtolower($_POST['stripe-currency']),
                             'description' => 'US Report',
                             'metadata' => [
                                             'Currency' => $_POST['stripe-currency'],
                                             'Invoice' => $_POST['ref_id'],
                                         ],
                            'receipt_email' => $email,
                         ), array (
                             'idempotency_key' => preg_replace('/[^a-z\d]/im', '', $_POST['idempotency']),
                         )
                     );
```

Comment: when i add that i get this..  `Charge creation failed! Status is:404
Type is:invalid_request_error
Code is:missing
Param is:source
Message is:Customer cus_HgMsasdadwqr does not have a linked source with ID tok_1H73g7DT9pjYPnb35vCd5ON7`

Comment: Hmm. After you created a customer, can you see if it has default source attached? `var_dump($customer->default_source);` According to [the documentation](https://stripe.com/docs/api/customers/create#create_customer-source), it should attach the source and make it default source for the customer.

Comment: Oh, I think I know what's wrong. Looks like you're using legacy Charges API. For that, when creating a customer, you should use `card` parameter to pass the token. So change `"source" => $token,` to `"card" => $token,` in your customer creation code and this should work.